# Ray Tracing Noise

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I was wondering if someone with ray tracing experience could help me figure out a couple problems in my program, however I cannot post much code as this program is a school assignment. I was just wondering if I could get some tips that could help steer me in the right direction. So thanks in advance!

First) As you can see, there's a ton of noise in my ray tracing image below. The scene consists of a single triangle hovering over a plane. There also exists a single point-light source.

Second) The noise doesn't occur when I compute shadow rays, however it calculates the wrong color for the shadow.

My ray-tracing algorithm:

```
for each pixel,
    color c;
    for each shape in the scene
        send a ray through each pixel and see if it collides with a shape
        if it does
            color = calculate color of ray
        else, color = background color
    return color

To calculate color of ray...
    color c = 0,0,0 // rgb
    for each light source in the scene
        make a new ray (shad_ray) that starts at where the original ray hit the shape...
        ... and ends at the light source
        see if the shadow ray hits a shape on its way to the light
        if it does, 
            calculate ambient color using ambient color of shape material and...
            ... ambient light intensity 
        if not,
            calculate shading with sum of ambient/diffuse/specular components
```

I know that's a really loose description of the algorithm. But I can provide more info if needed.

[image: Bad ray tracing </3]

Comment: I think you would feel better to learn that a professional ray tracing engine has serious problems with noise, too: https://brigade.otoy.com/gtc/brigade/2014/03/28/brigade-3-preview-at-gtc-2014.html -- watch their video; they acknowledge this problem but it's not clear when/if they'll find an acceptable solution that doesn't compromise graphics quality. Maybe they need higher bit depth floating point hardware on GPUs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks pretty familiar, and is called ["surface acne"](http://books.google.com/books?id=YPblYyLqBM4C&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=ray+tracing+acne&source=bl&ots=yZe92KlmQ9&sig=6Bo8kzVJcAYEEAGjDeQhYut1RjI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v-piU5OnEoz3oASpzoHACw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=ray%20tracing%20acne&f=false). A common error with ray-tracing shadows is that the shadow ray intersects the object the shadow ray is emanating from. Because of finite floating-point precision, the intersection point isn't always exactly on a surface - it ends up being slightly above or below. When you cast your shadow ray, you can intersect that surface again. It looks noisy because some locations do self-intersect and some don't

Typical ways to handle this are to move the origin of your shadow ray slightly back toward the eye point, or to ignore shadow intersections that occur within a very short distance, or to ignore all intersections with that surface (if your surface is planar or convex).

As for the color of shadowed areas, you'll likely have to post actual code but it looks like you're using the material of the object the shadow ray intersects instead of the primary ray.

Comment: Ahhh this is what my professor meant, okay. His instructions are vague, but I think you cleared it up. Thanks a lot!